# what is the total pixel of match parent of screen in android?

Tags: android, xml

Suppose if I am setting a horizontal orientation linear layout then what should be the total pixel of match parent so that I could adjust my buttons and text view according to that size.

I tried to place all margins and calculate...

the expected output would depend on screen size.

Comment: please make you question more clear, maybe with some examples and things you have tried

Comment: Have u check this [Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1016896/7666442)

Answer (score 1):

total pixels for `match_parent` of a view is depend on your `parentView` type, dimensions and composition of views within the layout, for example if your `parentView` is `LinearLayout` of size `100px * 100px` then your `match_parent` for a view within that `LinearLayout` is `100px * 100px` (iff you have only one view within that `LinearLayout` otherwise it depends on your composition) you can get your view's `height` and `width` (in pixels) programmatically to by using below code to any `view` or `Layout`

Java

```
view.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
         int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
         int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
    }
});
```

kotlin

```
view.post {
    val width = view.measuredWidth
    val height = view.measuredHeight
}
```

after getting height and width of layout you can manage you margin or size according to your logic

Answer (score 0):

The total pixels of `match parent` is the total pixels of the screen size, and if you to implement an auto resize for your views you should either use `constraint layout`as a parent layout for your views, either use this great library that uses a new size unit called `sdp` https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Answer (score 0):

Don't user pixels, it makes your screen not responsive to all screen sizes. use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)  or [Relative Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative) if you want your screen to be responsive to all screen sizes.

Here is an example of a view that his width is qeual to all of the screen size using ConstraintLayout :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```